# unable to pass # character via querystring

Tags: c#, jquery, query-string

I have a link being created in jquery that has a querystring value of "www.mypage.com?id=" + id

the problem I'm having is that in a recent case, some of the id's have the # character in them, which is breaking the id value.  How can I create a querystring with a # in it, from jquery, and read that value accurately in C# when the page loads?

Comment: You should *always* use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) when building URLs. There are many other characters besides `#` that require escaping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

[`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

before passing that.

Like:

```
"www.mypage.com?id=" + encodeURIComponent(id);
```

or just encode the entire url.

Comment: @aevitas, encoding the entire uri would encode the delimiters such as '&'...  you need to encode the specific, atomic, entities.

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass the `'#` as part of the id.  It is used to delimit parts of the url.  Either escape it or fix the code that is sending the `#` as part of the id (because I suspect it shouldn't).

Comment: I understand that, but it's a value from the database, an ID the client has created, and some of them have the # character in them

Comment: Personally, I'd never use a `#` for part of an identifier if I could possibly help it.  That said, as Amit points out, you'll have to encode the ids.

Answer (score 0):

You could find/replace instances of '#' and swap for '%23' which is the escape character.

For reference, I found this list of common escape characters in a quick Google search: http://www.werockyourweb.com/url-escape-characters

Comment: I added my answer before I saw yours. I upvoted your answer after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you, it is a small peace of code:

```
<body onload="catchingData()">


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function catchingData() {
        var myurl = document.URL;
        var myToken = myurl.split("access_token"); //---> Split your url in the browser
        self.location = "yourWebForm.aspx" + "?" + myToken[1];
    }
</script>
```